# Jquery datepicker reducing one day from selected epoch time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, epoch

I have two Jquery datepickers namely "startDate" and "endDate". I initialize them like this.

```
$(function() {

    $("#startdate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    $("#enddate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

});
```

Now i convert this date to epoch by doing this.

```
        var sDate = startdate.split('-');
        var eDate = enddate.split('-');
        var sepoch = new Date(sDate[0], sDate[1] - 1, sDate[2]).getTime() / 1000;
        var eepoch = new Date(eDate[0], eDate[1] - 1, eDate[2]).getTime() / 1000;
        startdate = sepoch.toString();
        enddate = eepoch.toString();
```

Now when i check the dates after converting them back from epoch, they differ by one day. So one day has been reduced from them. I can't figure out where i am going wrong. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the fiddle, I have added a bit of code and I am getting the date that I chose from the datepicker

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/L2ay1ax7/)

```
$("#startdate").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(date) {
            DoStuff();
        }
});

function DoStuff() {
  var startdate = $("#startdate").val();
  var sDate = startdate.split('-');
  var sepoch = new Date(sDate[0], sDate[1] - 1, sDate[2]).getTime() / 1000;
  var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
    d.setUTCSeconds(sepoch);
  console.log(sDate[2]);

  console.log(d);
}
```

Comment: so i am converting the epoch to date by doing something like this

Comment: var s = new Date(tfs * 1000);
         var e = new Date(tfe * 1000);
         var startDate =  s.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (s.getUTCMonth() + 1)+ '-' + s.getUTCDate();
                                           var endDate = e.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (e.getUTCMonth() + 1)+ '-' + e.getUTCDate();

Comment: May be something is wrong in this code here? Just wanted to share the whole code.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demo of the issue you are continuing to face so I can look at it? You see in the fiddle, in the console under developer tools, I am taking the date from the input, converting to epoch and then back to the correct date right?

Comment: So basically this is what i am trying to do in a crude way.

Comment: I still dont see the issue, look at my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/3xf6d60x/1/ You can see that the dates get set as they are supposed to, I picked dates from the datepicker and then wrote them to the console, I then used those UTC dates to fill your tfs and tfe variables that would have been set by the url, when I ran the fiddle the dates set were correct.

Comment: This is my code only. So my code is working fine for u? Are u able to get the same date back??

Comment: Same code i am using. But somehow it is still reducing one day from both the datepickers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107258/discussion-between-nikhil-tikoo-and-noctane).